# Run as Maven Test

Tags: unit-testing, maven, intellij-idea, integration-testing

Just moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ.

In eclipse you could right click a file -> run as -> maven test (and other choices).

I was just wondering how to set that up in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Intellij you don't need to use maven to run this test. Just run test from IDE and it will works (in standart keymap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>). Idea will use dependencies and classpath resultant from Maven configuration

Answer (score 1):

Install [Maven Run Helper plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea)

Answer (score 0):

Here! View->Tool Windows->Maven Projects. Open this maven project windows, and in this windows' toolbar, there is an icon like terminal, hold your courser on it and you will see the tips: Execute Maven Goal. Or you can just click the lifecycle.